# Ivy repreport taking a long time

Tags: repository, ivy

I'm trying to run the [Ivy `repreport`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/repreport.html) however it is taking a very long time (>48 hours before I kill it).

The repository that it is being run against is reasonably large but not ridiculously so (~150 Company artifacts and maybe ~1K dependencies).

Running with verbose produces no output.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be happening or how to speed it up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would limit the repreport to your organization like:

```
<ivy:repreport organisation="youroganization" />
```

This way artifacts that are not linked to your organization are ignored.

On my machine the first lines of output are:

```
ivy-report:
[ivy:repreport] :: resolving dependencies :: caller#all-caller;working
```

So getting no output at all is very suspicious, but I have no idea what could cause that.

And if all fails you could try to clean the cache.